# Tkinter Canvas is empty

Tags: python, canvas, python-3.x, tkinter

I took this code from the first example here http://zetcode.com/tkinter/drawing/ I refit it so that it would print a map in the same file. There are no inherent errors, and it goes through the loops and even hits all the if statements properly. But in the end the canvas/frame has nothing in it. Can anyone tell me why?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH, NW


    class Example(Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

            self.parent = parent        
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):

            self.parent.title("Board")        
            self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

            canvas = Canvas(self)

            #The first four parameters are the x,y coordinates of the two bounding points.
            #The top-left and the bottom-right. 
            color = ""
            for x in range(10):
                for y in range(10):
                    if type(landMass[x][y]) is Land:
                        color = "grey" 
                    if type(landMass[x][y]) is Food:
                        color = "green"
                    if type(landMass[x][y]) is Water:
                        color = "blue"
                    if type(landMass[x][y]) is Shelter:
                        color = "black"
                    rec = canvas.create_rectangle(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, 53 + 50 * y, 53 + 50 * x , fill=color)
                    text = canvas.create_text(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, anchor=NW, fill="white", text=landMass[x][y].elevation)

    def main():

        root = Tk()
        ex = Example(root)
        root.geometry("500x500+500+500")
        root.mainloop()  


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the link, you have omitted the call to `canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)` at the end of the function.

After here:

```
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        if type(landMass[x][y]) is Land:
            color = "grey" 
        if type(landMass[x][y]) is Food:
            color = "green"
        if type(landMass[x][y]) is Water:
            color = "blue"
        if type(landMass[x][y]) is Shelter:
            color = "black"
        rec = canvas.create_rectangle(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, 53 + 50 * y, 53 + 50 * x , fill=color)
        text = canvas.create_text(3 + 50 * y, 3 + 50 * x, anchor=NW, fill="white", text=landMass[x][y].elevation)
```

You should have:

```
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I had already tried that, and the link has the pack in the same place.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled Well you are wrong! I've tried it myself on your code and it works, it displays everything now after doing that. If you aren't packing the canvas obviously it's not going to show it

Comment: @EasilyBaffled The link has the `pack` in the right place but yours doesn't have it at all!

Comment: Ah you're right I see what the problem was, I miss read the self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1) as canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1), and that messed with everything